# Prevent default action of hyperlink not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make it so that when this link is clicked, `#pd` is not added to the address bar (url) and the link does not try to navigate to any location. However, I keep getting `#pd` in the address bar, although I am not being taken to the top of the page, which I would be normally.

How do I fix this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a[href=#pd]').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#pd">Click me</a>
```

Comment: works perfectly for me.

Comment: its working i checked

Comment: Stating the obvious, but did you include the jquery library before using that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/B4K9j/), difference between the two links can be seen with the color of the links when clicked. Note that url won't change in jsfiddle, but you could test this on a simple html page.

html

```
<a href="#pd">Won't mark as visited</a>
<a href="#not-pd">Will mark as visited</a>
```

javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a[href=#pd]').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Make sure you included jquery correctly, I am using jQuery 2.1.0 on the fiddle ;)